# Trouble Understanding PageRankCentrality function

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm doing a project in which I want to rank the nodes of a graph using page-rank centrality. The Mathematica documentation for `PageRankCentrality` is:

> PageRankCentrality[g, α], gives a list of page-rank centralities for the vertices in the graph g and weight α.

The function would then return the page-rank centralities of all nodes in the graph. My question is, is there a version of this such that I can apply it to an unweighted graph? This function requires a parameter "α" for the weight. If I put the weight to 1 or 0 for example, would that make the graph essentially unweighted? If not, what could be a possible solution to find the page-rank centrality of all nodes?

Comment: Thanks, so a weight of 0.5 makes the graph essentially unweighted?

Answer (score 3):

The second argument is not a *weight*, but the *damping factor*. I find the phrasing "weight" to be quite misleading.

The default damping factor is 0.85. This is unfortunately not documented, but it is the common default value used by most implementations, so it was not hard to guess and verify.